# Nearest Neighbors from KKNN package in R giving garbage indices values when the entire dataset is used

Tags: r, machine-learning, nearest-neighbor, knn

I am using "kknn" package in R to find all of the nearest neighbors for every row in the data set. For some odd reasons, the last row in the test dataset is always ignored. Below, is the R code and the output obtained.

```
X1 <- c(0.6439659, 0.1923593, 0.3905551, 0.7728847, 0.7602632)
X2 <- c(0.9147394, 0.6181713, 0.8515923, 0.8459367, 0.9296278)
Class <- c(1, 1, 0, 0, 0)
Data <- data.frame(X1,X2,Class)
Data$Class <- as.factor(Data$Class)
library("kknn")
### Here, both training and testing data sets is the object Data
Neighbors.KNN <- kknn(Data$Class~., Data,Data,k = 5, distance =2, kernel = "gaussian")

## Output 
## The Column 5 in the below output is filled with garbage values and the value of the first value in the last row is 4, when it has to be 5.
Neighbors.KNN$C  
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]    [,5]
[1,]    1    4    3    2 3245945
[2,]    2    3    4    1 3245945
[3,]    3    1    4    2 3245945
[4,]    4    1    3    2 3245945
[5,]    1    4    3    2 3245945
```

Could someone let me know if I am doing something wrong or if that is a bug in the package?

Answer (score 2):

the current implementation (silently) assumes that k is smaller than n, the number of rows. In general will be k << n and this case is no problem. The (k+1)th is used to scale distances. I should have mentioned this in the documentation.

Regards,
Klaus